# System.FormatException: 'The format of the input string is incorrect.'

Tags: c#

I am new with C# and I built a very basic calculator that allows a user to enter two numbers into two textboxes and an operator via buttons.  When the user clicks result, the calculator computes the result.

For getting user input, I have: `firstnumber = Double.Parse(fnum.Text);`.  The program compiles but throws the exception `System.FormatException: 'The format of the input string is incorrect.'`.

I have also tried `firstnumber = Convert.ToDouble(fnum.Text);` but got the same exception.

Here is my code:

```
namespace Bear3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private double firstnumber;
        private double secondnumber;
        private double resultt=0;
        private bool plusch = false;
        private bool minusch = false;
        private bool multiplicationch = false;
        private bool divisionch = false;
        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Operator.Text="+";
            plusch = true;
        }

        private void Label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Fnum_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                firstnumber = Convert.ToDouble(fnum.Text);


        }

        private void Label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Minus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Operator.Text = "-";
            minusch = true;
        }

        private void Multiplication_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Operator.Text = "*";
            multiplicationch = true;
        }

        private void Division_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Operator.Text = "/";
            divisionch = true;
        }

        private void Result_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (plusch == true)
            {
                resultt = firstnumber + secondnumber;
            }
            else if (minusch == true)
            {
                resultt = firstnumber - secondnumber;
            }
            else if (multiplicationch == true)
            {
                resultt = firstnumber * secondnumber;
            }
            else if (divisionch == true)
            {
                resultt = firstnumber / secondnumber;
            }
            ResultShow.Text = Convert.ToString(resultt);

        }

        private void Snum_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                secondnumber = Double.Parse(snum.Text);


        }

        private void Clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            plusch = false;
            minusch = false;
            multiplicationch = false;
            divisionch = false;
            ResultShow.Text = "";
            Operator.Text = "";
            fnum.Text = "";
            snum.Text = "";


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: Now is a good time to familiarize yourself with the use of a debugger.  In Visual Studio you can set debugging breakpoints to pause the execution of the code and allow you to step through line by line and observe what each line does to your variables.  Place a breakpoint just before the line that throws the exception.  (Or at the beginning of the method which throws the exception if you're unsure.)  Before you execute that line, what is the string value that you're trying to parse?  Why do you think it should be parsed successfully?

Comment: You are going to get that exception whenever text that is not able to be converted to a double is entered. Ex: `2a` won't parse because of the letter. Are you receiving this error still when you test with a basic number (like `3`)?

Comment: Yes i put only number like 2 in the first textbox and 3 in the second textbox and i get the result correctly but after the result is shown the program crashs

Comment: Which line of code is throwing that exception? The stack trace should tell you.

Comment: here:  firstnumber = Convert.ToDouble(fnum.Text);

Comment: When you need to read input from your users the answer is always the same. Use the TryParse methods and handle the return value of this method. In your case _double.TryParse_

Comment: and the error message is shown when i press the clear button, is it the clear that makes the issue? and sorry for my english

Comment: but when i use tryparse i need a out ....

Comment: how do i change  firstnumber = Convert.ToDouble(fnum.Text); to tryparse?

Comment: If the error message shows on clear, then the text in the box is changing (which fires your TextChanged event). The now empty textbox will not parse because an empty string is not a double. Add a check to make sure the string is not empty. Also take Steve's advice and use `double.TryParse`

Comment: I found the problem i removed fnum.Text = "";
            snum.Text = ""; from the clear and the message did not showed any solutions for the clear?

Comment: @MirouLatif you want to clear your text boxes when the user clicks the clear button. That isn't the issue. See my answer for help parsing safely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than getting the variables on TextChanged which can fire more often than you expect, do it on the Result click action.

Move these lines to the top of the Result_Click and remove them from their current spot.

```
firstnumber = Convert.ToDouble(fnum.Text);   
secondnumber =Convert.ToDouble(snum.Text);
```

I do recommend you check to see if the data is actually a Double so you don't get an error.

Comment: man you're a genius thank you it worked   : i puted that directly in the Result_Click           if (plusch == true)
            {
                resultt = (firstnumber = Convert.ToDouble(fnum.Text)) + (secondnumber = Convert.ToDouble(snum.Text));
            }

Answer (score 0):

Update your `Fnum_TextChanged` and `Snum_TextChanged` methods to validate the text when parsing:

```
private void Fnum_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fnum.Text)) 
    { 
        if (double.TryParse(fnum.Text, out firstnumber) == false){
            // notify user in message box or throw error
        }
    }
}
```

After this runs, if there is no error that means `fnum.Text` parsed and is now stored in your `firstnumber` variable.

Comment: `if (!double.TryParse(fnum.Text, out firstnumber)){...}` is more natural

Comment: Very true, but for someone just learning the language, `== false` is easier to read.